# Expectation maximization: does the likelihood always increase monotonically?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, finite-mixture-model, multinomial-dirichlet-distribution

When working with (gaussian) mixture models, I always took it for a mathematical fact that the marginal likelihood increases with every iteration step. If it were not the case, it always meant an error in the code or some other technical problem.

I am now experimenting with Dirichlet mixture models, where the maximization step is done numerically. One is then not guaranteed to find the absolute maximum of the expected likelihood, so *intuitively* non-monotonous increase of the marginal likelihood seems not fully disallowed. And I do see it in my simulations.

Is this known behavior? Or are there mathematical results showing that the likelihood should still increase monotonically?

I will appreciate help from experienced people.

**Remark:**
(Two weeks on) I did find an error in my DMM code, but I think the question still stands.

Comment: Likelihood decreases or increases?

Comment: @mhdadk it increases, but in practice one usually minimize negative log-likelihood. I corrected it.

Comment: @mhdadk This question is about *maximization.*

Comment: @whuber yes that is why I was confused when OP said "likelihood decreases", so I was asking for clarification.